# Excel: Find results in column, and then search all matched rows for another value and return sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am totally lost on this, I've tried a dozen different combinations of formula functions but I'm lost and was hoping someone could help me out.

```
name|1|2|3|4|5|6
----------------
bob | |x| |x|x| 
tim | |x|x| | |x
bob | |x| | |x| 
bob | | | |x| | 
tim | |x| | | | 
bob | |x| |x|x| 
tim | |x| | | |x
```

I want to be search for bob and get the total number of Xs, same thing for tim. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Look intp [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842)

Comment: Question-askers tend to get more sympathy and help when they (1) *show* what they tried (rather than just waving their hands and saying, ‘‘I’ve tried a dozen different combinations of formula functions’’, and (2) show what results they want from sample input data.

Comment: Better share with us all that (Formula & Methods) you have tried so far,, will help us to guide you !!

Comment: 1. So the column headers 1 through 6 are just labels, not actual values that have any relevance to the result?  2. Column position is irrelevant to the count; Bob having multiple X's in some of the columns doesn't affect the raw count?  3. It would be clearer if you edit the question to show what you expect the results to be for this example.  e.g., are Bob: 9; tim: 6 the correct totals as you want to count them?  4. Do you want to enter a search term and get a count for that name, or generate a table or list of results that include all the names and their respective counts?  (cont'd)

Comment: 5. Will the data be growing or changing over time? If so, do you need results in a form that is always current when the data changes, or in that case do you not care if you need to refresh the results whenever the data changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it could be easiest to use `SUMPRODUCT`

[image]

Formula used in `J2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:G8="x")*(A2:A8=J1))
```